# does a circle between tables in oracle violate any normalization?

Tags: oracle, normalization

i Want to Know if i Have a Circle Between my Tables in Oracle,Does it Violate any Normalization? if it Does,Which Kind of Normalization This Violate?
some thing like this image[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram isn't actually cyclic. A references B and D, C references B and D. There's nothing wrong with that in any normalisation I'm aware of.

I'm not sure if cycles are specifically forbidden, but they're extremely difficult to deal with because once you've set up a cycle with referential integrity (assuming all references are non-optional) you can't actually delete any of it without disabling the constraints while you do it. So I'd try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: You can easily delete from cyclic references (and insert them even when the FK columns are defined as NOT NULL) when using deferred constraints.